# Compare to all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to compare a vector of values with all columns of a table in SQL, more specifically in MS SQL Server?

For example, I have a table, EXAMPLE, with 3 columns:

```
EXAMPLE: ColA, ColB, ColC
```

And I want to check if its columns match a specific vector: ('val0', 'val1', 'val2')

I know I can do that with a sentence like this:

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ColA='val0' AND ColB = 'val1' AND ColC = 'val2'
```

But I'd like to know if there is some function, ALLEQUAL which could allow me to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ALLEQUAL('val0', 'val1', 'val2');
```

I understand that if that function exists its syntax may be quite different between different RDBMSs and I now focused on Ms SQL Server. Nevertheless I will be more than happy if you can give me examples in other databases managers.

Comment: you would still have to specify the set / ordering of column names to match? in which case it couldn't be much more concise than the query with multiple AND's?

Comment: Some RDBMSs allow you to compare tuples but SQL Server doesn't.

Comment: Please, Martin, could you give me an example of that?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6b7c/1)

Comment: @MartinSmith, That is exactly what I wanted. Its a pity MSSQL doesn't allow it.
"SELECT * 
FROM EXAMPLE
WHERE (ColA,ColB,ColC) = ('val0', 'val1','val2')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @Foo as Table ( ColA Int, ColB Int );
insert into @Foo ( ColA, ColB ) values ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 2 ), ( 2, 1 );
select * from @Foo;

select *
  from @Foo
  intersect
  select *
    from ( values ( 2, 1 ) ) as Bar( ColA, ColB );
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM @Foo WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  2, 1 INTERSECT SELECT ColA, ColB)` would be better as it doesn't have the implied `DISTINCT` of intersect and also allows additional columns from Foo to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you

```
SELECT * 
FROM EXAMPLE 
WHERE ColA+ColB+ColC = 'val0'+'val1'+'val2'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a well designed database the tables will have a PRIMARY KEY, the key will be a unique identifier for the row, because of this there is no need to match the rest of the 'vector' in your scenario.

Now if you have some flat de-normalized data you could create an sproc that generates dynamic sql to do what you want. You'd have to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns or sys.columns and generate something similar to the first SQL statement you wrote ~"WHERE ColA='val0' AND ColB = 'val1' AND ColC = 'val2' "

Here's the varchar column only approach using FOR XML PATH('')

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(c1 VARCHAR(max), c2 VARCHAR(max), c3 VARCHAR(max))
DECLARE @vec TABLE(data VARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('abc', '123', 'xyz'), ('cba', '321', 'zyx')
INSERT INTO @vec VALUES ('abc'), ('123'), ('xyz')
SELECT * FROM @tbl
WHERE c1+c2+c3 = (SELECT '' + data FROM @vec FOR XML PATH(''))
END
```

Comment: Let suppose ('val0','val1','val2') is not a constant value but the result of a select. There are cases where you may want to compare if the result of a subquery match all columns values.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo - in that case you would have to define the columns you want to compare the vector which is very different from some ALLEQUAL( vector ) function. Should ALLEQUAL ignore the primary and foreign key columns? what about timestamps? Should null values in the vector be ignore in the comparison or compared exactly IS NULL?